# Sequence with convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f(x, y) = \bigg(\frac{3x + 4y}{5}, \frac{-4x + 3y}{5}\bigg)$, and point $\mathbf{p} = (1, 1)$ and consider the sequence $\lbrace \mathbf{p}, f(\mathbf{p}), f(f(\mathbf{p})), f(f(f(\mathbf{p}))), \cdots\rbrace$. I want to show that this has a convergent subsequence. To do this , I want to show that is is bounded and then apply the bounded sequence theorem. I have tried expanding out the first few terms but that didn't seem to get me anywhere. Is this a good approach, if so what am I missing here? If not, what is a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ has this property: $\bigl\lVert f(x,y)\bigr\rVert=\bigl\lVert(x,y)\bigr\rVert$, for every $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$. So, every element of your sequence your sequence belongs to $\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,\middle|\,\bigl\lVert(x,y)\bigr\rVert=\sqrt2\right\}$, which is compact. Therefore, yes, your sequence has a convergent subsequence indeed.